# Does firebase's updateProfile return the user in the Promise

Tags: javascript, firebase

I was trying to do something like:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.updateProfile({displayName: 'test'})
  .then(user => {
   console.log(user);
  })
  .catch(err => {
   console.log(err);
  }
```

but the console user is showing nothing. Does it not return anything in the promise?

Comment: *"Does it not return anything in the promise?"* that would be a quite accurate observation.

Answer (score 8):

Per the [Firebase documentation on `updateProfile`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#updateProfile):

> `updateProfile` **returns non-null firebase.Promise containing void**
>
> An example for this:
>
> ```
>    // Updates the user attributes:
> user.updateProfile({
>   displayName: "Jane Q. User",
>   photoURL: "https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"
> }).then(function() {
>   // Profile updated successfully!
>   // "Jane Q. User"
>   var displayName = user.displayName;
>   // "https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"
>   var photoURL = user.photoURL;
> }, function(error) {
>   // An error happened.
> });
>
> // Passing a null value will delete the current attribute's value, but not
> // passing a property won't change the current attribute's value:
> // Let's say we're using the same user than before, after the update.
> user.updateProfile({photoURL: null}).then(function() {
>   // Profile updated successfully!
>   // "Jane Q. User", hasn't changed.
>   var displayName = user.displayName;
>   // Now, this is null.
>   var photoURL = user.photoURL;
> }, function(error) {
>   // An error happened.
> });
> ```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. Although it should have been trivial for the asker to look this info up himself, this is still the right answer.